# Clearing String/Text

Tags: string, text, javafx

Redirect me if this is already a previously solved issue!

In my program, I have a Stage in which the user can view a list of content, stored in a list consisting of Strings.

```
goToView.setOnAction(event ->{
        menuStage.close(); 
        viewStage.show();
        String horseNameList = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < accountList.size(); i++){
            if(accountList.get(i).userName.equals(uName)){
                for(int j = 0; j < accountList.get(i).createdHorses.size(); j++){
                    horseNameList += accountList.get(i).createdHorses.get(j);
                    horseNameList += "\n" + "\n";
                }
            }
            Text hNameListTXT = new Text(horseNameList);
            hNameListTXT.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 12));
            listVbox.getChildren().add(hNameListTXT);
        }
```

createdHorses is a List of Strings, listVbox is as you may think a VBox where the String (which converts to a Text) is printed. Now, when I close the Stage with the following EventHandler, nothing in particular happens: 
`backView.setOnAction(event -> {
            viewStage.close();
            menuStage.show();
});`

But as I then open the Stage once again (by using another EventHandler similar to the one I use to close the first Stage with), my List (or String) har been doubled. What should I do to clear the String (or possibly the Text) so that it doesn't display it twice?

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do to clear the String (or possibly the Text) so that it
>   doesn't display it twice?

The [VBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html) has a method [getChildren()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html#getChildren--) which returns an [ObservableList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html). So you could use [clear()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html?is-external=true#clear--) on it to remove all the children.